# Search for parts of a string in a content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-cursorloader

Hello I'm implementing a searchview and inside `onQueryTextChange`, every time the user press a letter I want to search that in my DB. The `onQueryTextChange` is implemented and working, I need help with the search, for example:

```
String selection = AplicationContract.ArtistEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { "MAX" };

            return new CursorLoader(getContext(),   
                    AplicationContract.ArtistEntry.CONTENT_URI,   
                    AplicationContract.ArtistEntry.PROJECTION,             
                    selection,                   
                    selectionArgs,                   
                    null);
```

That returns me a cursor if I have a name "MAX" in my db. But if the names in my db are "MAX","MASON","MEGAN","SEAN" so when I hit the letter M I want to search in my content provider for any name with the letter M, the result would be "MAX","MASON","MEGAN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using like statement, you should code like this demo:

```
select * from tb where c like "%M%"
```

just learn how to use it on this site: http://www.w3school.com

In this case, you should correct the params:

```
String[] selectionArgs = { "M"+"%" };
```

Comment: Ty mate the String[] selectionArgs = { "%"+"M"+"%" }; is working, tho the page you linked, I don't what has to do with the question

Comment: sorry. w3cschool is a chinese site :< http://www.w3school.com.cn/sql/sql_like.asp